# ColdFusion cfinvoke (Message Security - ClientCredentials = Username)

Tags: wcf, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have a WCF Service endpoint. The service is configured as a WCF service with Security Mode = TransportWithMessageCredential and Message security clientCredentialType set to Username using a CustomValidator for username/password validation.

I have this code in a c# Console Application (which works):

```
   ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myusername";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "mypassword";
    Console.WriteLine(client.GetVersion());
```

The code above works - what is the ColdFusion equivalent using cfinvoke?
I currently have the following (which worked okay before username/password introduction)

```
<cfinvoke  
webservice="#wsurl#"
method="getVersion" 
returnvariable="gcversion"
refreshwsdl="true">  
</cfinvoke>
```

Where is the appropriate place to include the 'Client Credentials'?

**EDIT**: It seems that the service is using 'WS-Security'. I am struggling to find information on CF2016's support for WS-Security. It seems this is a standard so I am unsure of why finding info has been difficult.

If anyone could provide any resource, I would be really grateful.

**EDIT2**:
I am trying to do this:
```

    ws = CreateObject("webservice", wsurl, {refreshwsdl=true});

```
objSoapHeader = XmlParse("<wsse:Security mustUnderstand=""false"" xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd""><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>myun</wsse:Username><wsse:Password>mypass</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>");

addSOAPRequestHeader(ws, "ignoredNameSpace", "ignoredName", objSoapHeader,false);

version =ws.getVersion();
writeOutput(version);
```

but am receiving the following error:

```
Cannot perform web service invocation getVersion.
The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security

    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.checkMustUnderstand(AxisEngine.java:105)

    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:171)

    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:364)

    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)

    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)

    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)

    at cwtgift.CWTGiftServiceStub.getVersion(CWTGiftServiceStub.java:1954)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

     The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion2016/cfusion/wwwroot/test/getVersion.cfm: line 19

    17 :     addSOAPRequestHeader(ws, "ignoredNameSpace", "ignoredName", objSoapHeader,false);
    18 : 
    19 :     version =ws.getVersion();
    20 :     writeOutput(version);
    21 : </cfscript>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing specifics of your ServiceClient(), I suspect using cfinvokeargument is probably the quickest way to pass in your username/password:

```
<cfinvoke webservice="#wsurl#"
    method="getVersion" 
    returnvariable="gcversion"
    refreshwsdl="true">

    <cfinvokeargument name="UserName" value="myusername" />
    <cfinvokeargument name="Password" value="mypassword" />

</cfinvoke>
```

If you have a need to hit an endpoint that is not configured as a web service, you can also use CFHTTP in a similar fashion (I haven't detailed all arguments or values here, you'll want to refer to https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html for all the details):

```
<cfhttp url="" method="" throwOnError="" multipart="" path="" file="" name=""  result="">

    <cfhttpparam type="" name="UserName" value="myusername" />
    <cfhttpparam type="" name="Password" value="mypassword" />

</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Added Additional details to the question

Comment: Is it basic authentication? If so, try the username and password attributes instead.

Comment: Hi @Leigh, I do not believe it is basic authentication. It is the WSS authentication. In Soap UI I need to set the WSS Password Type to 'Text' and then use the username and password under basic.

I have tried to use the username and password attributes, as well as setting the authType to BASIC

Comment: (Edit) I am surprised setting it to BASIC did not work, especially if you are refreshing the webservice ie `refreshWSDL`. I do not know if it works, but for WSS might try this snippet http://www.mikeobrien.net/blog/consuming-web-service-that-requires-wss

Comment: Will try that when I am back in the office @Leigh - Thank you so much

Comment: Tried to get that to work - but could not @Leigh. It seems CF is seriously lacking support for WS-Security. I am using Coldfusion 2016 if that helps - I will update my question.